# call a custom JS function once

Tags: 8, javascript

I understand once() can be used on a jquery selector method to make sure it is triggered only once.

How to do the same with custom functions?

My function `wakeUpAndRemember` is called 5 times which is problematic.

```
(function ($, Drupal) {
  Drupal.behaviors.recherche = {
    attach: function (context) {  
      ...      
      wakeUpAndRemember(mapObj);           
    }
  };
(jQuery, Drupal);
```

Comment: Can't you apply it to `body` or `html` then with `.once()`?

Comment: If you don't want to use jquery selectors to attach something then don't use drupal behaviors attach().

Comment: Yes, there's nothing stopping you coding the function invocation outside behaviors as in regular JS, the purpose of behaviors is to ensure you can reprocess the DOM when stuff is injected via AJAX, it's not mandatory for all purposes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could set a global variable and then set it in your wakeUpAndRemember function

```
var do_once = false;
function wakeUpAndRemember() {
  console.log('test');
  do_once = true;
}
Drupal.behaviors.recherche = {
    attach: function (context, settings) {
      if (do_once == false){
        wakeUpAndRemember();
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: it does not work coz var do_once= false is called 5 times too.

Comment: It shouldn't do if you do exactly like what I've done. Put the declaration of the variable outside of any behaviour/function and it will only be defined once when the file is loaded into the browser. If you have it inside of a behaviour/function that gets called by a behaviour then yes of course it will get initialised every time

Answer (score 3):

Another option is to use [underscore's once function](https://underscorejs.org/#once).

```
# your_theme_or_module.libraries.yml
global-styling:
  js:
    js/main.js: {}
  dependencies:
    - core/underscore



// js/main.js
(function ($, _, Drupal) {

  "use strict";

  Drupal.behaviors.example = {

    attach: _.once(function(context, settings) {
      // do stuff once.
    })

  }

})(jQuery, _, Drupal);
```

Underscore comes bundled in Drupal 8 by default.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is possible using `.once()`, but you can do it by setting a variable in your function and only running the function if that variable is not set.

Your function shall look like this:

```
var wakeUpAndRemember = (function(mapObj) {
  var executed = false;
  return function() {
    if (!executed) {
      executed = true;
      // The code from your function goes in here.
    }
  };
})();
```

Comment: the script is never interpreted below that line.if (!executed) {console.log("entering here") do not show anything

Comment: yes i think i did